# Comparing a FACT table and a DIMENSION table's two columns for NULL and NOT NULL answers

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Im looking to compare a dimension table with a table that gets data  loaded into it daily.

the dimension table contains two columns... lets call them Name and Name_ID and the daily table contains the same columns with many more other columns

```
>+-------+-------+
|Name   |Name_ID|
+-------+-------+
|value1 |value1 |
|value2 |value3 |
|value4 |value4 |
>+-------+-------+
```

What I need to do is compare the tables to see if the value being imported into the daily table is contained in the Dimension table then add the Name_ID into daily but keep Name as NULL 
OR
if the value of Name is not in the dimension table then just add the Name to the daily table and leave Name_ID as NULL

I understand it is a simple compare, and I can do it in a c# script, but I was looking for more of a solution in SSIS or maybe just a SQL script.

Thank you

Comment: "and I can do it in a c# script, but I was looking for more of a solution in SSIS or maybe just a SQL script." - Why? If it works well why would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO dim_table (Name, Name_ID)
SELECT NULL as Name, Name_ID
FROM daily_table x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM dim_table y
   WHERE x.Name_ID = y.Name_ID
   )
UNION 
SELECT Name, NULL as Name_ID
FROM daily_table x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM dim_table y
   WHERE x.Name = y.Name
   )
```

Comment: thanks i'll try it out and let you know how it works !

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dimtab (Name, Name_ID)
SELECT NULL as Name, Name_ID FROM dailytab t1
     WHERE Name_ID NOT IN (SELECT NAME_ID FROM dimtab t2 
                                WHERE t1.Name_ID = t2.Name_ID)
UNION 
SELECT Name, NULL as Name_ID FROM dailytab t1
     WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM dimtab t2 
                                WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name)
```